# Does apt-cache only show you results based in what is installed?

Tags: linux, apt-get

If I run the command `apt-cache showpkg {packagename}`, does it only show the details of the package of it is installed or does it not matter? If I run the command `apt-get update`, does this update apt-get's cache and hence showing me all the package details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apt-get update downloads the package lists and metadata to your local box. With apt-cache  you look up stuff in the local data (local "apt cache").

See more information at

```
man apt-cache
```

Comment: Thanks. So does `apt-get update` update the apt cache? If not where does `apt-cache` get its information from?

Comment: Let me help you finding that information out by yourself. Run strace -f -e trace=open apt-cache search test |less and see the output. You will find lines such as open("/var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.hosteurope.de_mirror_archive.ubuntu.com_dists_hardy-security_universe_binary-amd64_Packages", O_RDONLY) = 8
which leads you to the folder /var/lib/apt/lists. This is only one of them, usually /var/lib/apt and /var/lib/dpkg contain the locally stored information.